# sistema de reservas en firebase

Tags: javascript, html, firebase

Estoy tratando de hacer un pequeño sistema de reservas usando firebase lo que pasa es que quiero que para una fecha y hora me valide si no a ocupado la cantidad maxima de personas que han reservado y si llego al limite no deje almacenar mas del cupo puesto

```
    const config = {
      apiKey: "AIzaSyA-1eW-ULwBF5i6q4EvH1BQF3MmIG8Y2Mk",
      authDomain: "pruba1-70047.firebaseapp.com",
      databaseURL: "https://pruba1-70047.firebaseio.com",
      projectId: "pruba1-70047",
      storageBucket: "pruba1-70047.appspot.com",
      messagingSenderId: "91492391659",
      appId: "1:91492391659:web:4861e4a5a3dfbc4aae7cae",
      measurementId: "G-NVDZF7ZLF6"
    };
      firebase.initializeApp(config); //inicializamos firebase
var db=firebase.firestore()  // inicializamos la firestore
    
    var Registrar = document.getElementById('Crear')
    Registrar.addEventListener('submit', Reserva)
    function Reserva (e) {
            e.preventDefault()
             //capturamos los input
             const Nombre = document.getElementById('Nombre').value
             const Fecha = document.getElementById('Fecha').value
             const Hora = document.getElementById('Hora').value
             const personas = document.getElementById('personas').value
             const Comentarios = document.getElementById('Comentarios').value
             const persona = 30
        
             if(personas <= persona && personas>=1){
              db.collection('reservas').doc().set({
                Nombre:Nombre, 
                Fecha:Fecha,
                Hora:Hora,
                Personas:personas,
                Comentarios:Comentarios
              });
              
             }
            Registrar.reset()
    }
```

Comment: Esa apikey, no hay lío en compartirla acá??

Answer (score 0):

Una solucion es que veas en todas las reservas que has echo la hora y fecha y ver si por ejemplo tu maximo de reservas son 10, comparar si has llegado a ese limite.

Mira me explico supongamos que queremos guardar para el dia 12 de febrero a las 10:00, entonces tendrias que verificar en todas las reservas que has echo si hay alguna que ya tengan la misma fecha, podrias iterar todas las reservas y sumar una variable que sea la cantidad de reservas para esa fecha. Luego lo comparas y si no hay el limite lo guardas.

Comment: eso es lo que trato de hacer pero no se como , porque intente consultando a la db y no me da , modificando personas en la db y cada q agrego una me lo edita mas no lo mantiene